# jupyter: 'notebook' is not a Jupyter command

Tags: python, macos, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am not sure how to make the command `jupyter notebook` to work:

```
 ~   progress ✚  sudo pip install --user ipython                                                                                                              01:45:27 AM
The directory '/Users/mona/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/mona/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting ipython
  Downloading ipython-5.3.0-py2-none-any.whl (750kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 757kB 944kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: pygments in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython)
Requirement already satisfied: pexpect; sys_platform != "win32" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython)
Requirement already satisfied: backports.shutil-get-terminal-size; python_version == "2.7" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython)
Requirement already satisfied: simplegeneric>0.8 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython)
Requirement already satisfied: traitlets>=4.2 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython)
Collecting setuptools>=18.5 (from ipython)
  Downloading setuptools-34.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (389kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 399kB 1.7MB/s
Collecting pathlib2; python_version == "2.7" or python_version == "3.3" (from ipython)
  Downloading pathlib2-2.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.4 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython)
Collecting pickleshare (from ipython)
  Downloading pickleshare-0.7.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting appnope; sys_platform == "darwin" (from ipython)
  Downloading appnope-0.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: ptyprocess>=0.5 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from pexpect; sys_platform != "win32"->ipython)
Requirement already satisfied: enum34; python_version == "2.7" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from traitlets>=4.2->ipython)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from traitlets>=4.2->ipython)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython-genutils in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from traitlets>=4.2->ipython)
Requirement already satisfied: appdirs>=1.4.0 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from setuptools>=18.5->ipython)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=16.8 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from setuptools>=18.5->ipython)
Collecting scandir; python_version < "3.5" (from pathlib2; python_version == "2.7" or python_version == "3.3"->ipython)
  Downloading scandir-1.5.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: wcwidth in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.4->ipython)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from packaging>=16.8->setuptools>=18.5->ipython)
Installing collected packages: setuptools, scandir, pathlib2, pickleshare, appnope, ipython
  Running setup.py install for scandir ... done
Successfully installed appnope-0.1.0 ipython-5.3.0 pathlib2-2.2.1 pickleshare-0.7.4 scandir-1.5 setuptools-34.3.0
 ~   progress ✚  jupyter notebook                                                                                                                             01:45:46 AM
jupyter: 'notebook' is not a Jupyter command
 ~   progress ✚  sudo pip install --user notebook                                                                                                       ➶ 1  01:55:03 AM
Password:
The directory '/Users/mona/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/mona/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting notebook
  Downloading notebook-4.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.9MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 6.9MB 172kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from notebook)
Requirement already satisfied: traitlets in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from notebook)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython-genutils in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from notebook)
Collecting ipykernel (from notebook)
  Downloading ipykernel-4.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (98kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 102kB 5.3MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: nbconvert in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from notebook)
Collecting jupyter-client (from notebook)
  Downloading jupyter_client-5.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (83kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 2.8MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: nbformat in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from notebook)
Requirement already satisfied: tornado>=4 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from notebook)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-core in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from notebook)
Collecting terminado>=0.3.3; sys_platform != "win32" (from notebook)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from jinja2->notebook)
Requirement already satisfied: enum34; python_version == "2.7" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from traitlets->notebook)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from traitlets->notebook)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from traitlets->notebook)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython>=4.0.0 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from ipykernel->notebook)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from nbconvert->notebook)
Requirement already satisfied: mistune!=0.6 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from nbconvert->notebook)
Requirement already satisfied: entrypoints in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from nbconvert->notebook)
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.1 (from jupyter-client->notebook)
  Downloading python_dateutil-2.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (194kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 194kB 3.1MB/s
Collecting pyzmq>=13 (from jupyter-client->notebook)
  Downloading pyzmq-16.0.2-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.whl (1.1MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.1MB 965kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.0 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from nbformat->notebook)
Requirement already satisfied: backports.ssl_match_hostname in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from tornado>=4->notebook)
Requirement already satisfied: singledispatch in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from tornado>=4->notebook)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/certifi-14.05.14-py2.7.egg (from tornado>=4->notebook)
Requirement already satisfied: backports_abc>=0.4 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from tornado>=4->notebook)
Requirement already satisfied: ptyprocess in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from terminado>=0.3.3; sys_platform != "win32"->notebook)
Requirement already satisfied: pexpect; sys_platform != "win32" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->notebook)
Requirement already satisfied: backports.shutil-get-terminal-size; python_version == "2.7" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->notebook)
Requirement already satisfied: simplegeneric>0.8 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->notebook)
Collecting setuptools>=18.5 (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->notebook)
  Downloading setuptools-34.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (389kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 399kB 1.8MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: pathlib2; python_version == "2.7" or python_version == "3.3" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->notebook)
Requirement already satisfied: prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.4 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->notebook)
Requirement already satisfied: pickleshare in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->notebook)
Requirement already satisfied: appnope; sys_platform == "darwin" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->notebook)
Requirement already satisfied: configparser>=3.5; python_version == "2.7" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from entrypoints->nbconvert->notebook)
Requirement already satisfied: functools32; python_version == "2.7" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.0->nbformat->notebook)
Requirement already satisfied: appdirs>=1.4.0 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from setuptools>=18.5->ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->notebook)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=16.8 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from setuptools>=18.5->ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->notebook)
Requirement already satisfied: scandir; python_version < "3.5" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pathlib2; python_version == "2.7" or python_version == "3.3"->ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->notebook)
Requirement already satisfied: wcwidth in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.4->ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->notebook)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from packaging>=16.8->setuptools>=18.5->ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->notebook)
Installing collected packages: python-dateutil, pyzmq, jupyter-client, ipykernel, terminado, notebook, setuptools
Successfully installed ipykernel-4.5.2 jupyter-client-5.0.0 notebook-4.4.1 python-dateutil-2.6.0 pyzmq-16.0.2 setuptools-34.3.0 terminado-0.6
 ~   progress ✚  jupyter notebook                                                                                                                             01:55:41 AM
jupyter: 'notebook' is not a Jupyter command
 ~   progress ✚  which jupyter                                                                                                                          ➶ 1  01:55:43 AM
/usr/local/bin/jupyter
 ~   progress ✚  which pip                                                                                                                                    01:56:36 AM
/usr/local/bin/pip
 ~   progress ✚  which python                                                                                                                                 01:56:39 AM
/usr/bin/python
 ~   progress ✚  pip -V                                                                                                                                       01:56:42 AM
pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
 ~   progress ✚  which ipython                                                                                                                                01:56:45 AM
 ~   progress ✚ 

 ~   progress ✚  sudo pip install --user ipython-notebook                                                                                                     01:59:01 AM
Password:
The directory '/Users/mona/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/mona/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting ipython-notebook
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ipython-notebook (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for ipython-notebook
```

my system info:

```
 ~   progress ✚  uname -a                                                                                                                               ➶ 1  01:58:20 AM
Darwin Monas-MacBook-Pro.local 15.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 15.6.0: Thu Jun 23 18:25:34 PDT 2016; root:xnu-3248.60.10~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

my pip list:

```
bash-4.3$ pip list
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
alabaster (0.7.6)
altgraph (0.10.2)
appdirs (1.4.2)
appnope (0.1.0)
arff (0.9)
Babel (2.0)
backports-abc (0.4)
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size (1.0.0)
backports.ssl-match-hostname (3.5.0.1)
bdist-mpkg (0.5.0)
BeautifulSoup (3.2.1)
beautifulsoup4 (4.3.2)
binaryornot (0.2.0)
bonjour-py (0.3)
butterfly (2.0.1)
catkin-pkg (0.2.9)
certifi (14.5.14)
click (6.2)
config (0.3.9)
configparser (3.5.0)
cookiecutter (0.7.0)
coverage (4.0a6)
cssselect (0.9.1)
Cython (0.19.2)
decorator (4.0.10)
distribute (0.7.3)
Django (1.6)
docutils (0.12)
ecdsa (0.13)
empy (3.3.2)
entrypoints (0.2.2)
enum34 (1.1.6)
Flask (0.10.1)
functools32 (3.2.3-2)
futures (2.2.0)
gnip-powertrack-rules (0.2.2)
goslate (1.3.0)
ipykernel (4.5.2)
ipython (5.3.0)
ipython-genutils (0.1.0)
itsdangerous (0.24)
Jinja2 (2.8)
jsonschema (2.5.1)
jupyter-client (5.0.0)
jupyter-core (4.2.0)
macholib (1.5.1)
MarkupSafe (0.23)
matplotlib (1.3.1)
microsofttranslator (0.6)
mistune (0.7.3)
mock (1.3.0)
modulegraph (0.10.4)
nbconvert (4.2.0)
nbformat (4.1.0)
netifaces (0.10.4)
nltk (2.0.4)
nose (1.3.7)
notebook (4.4.1)
numpy (1.8.0rc1)
packaging (16.8)
pandas (0.12.0)
paramiko (1.15.2)
pathlib2 (2.2.1)
pbr (1.3.0)
pexpect (4.2.1)
pickleshare (0.7.4)
Pillow (2.9.0)
pip (9.0.1)
prettytable (0.7.2)
prompt-toolkit (1.0.7)
psutil (3.1.1)
ptyprocess (0.5.1)
py2app (0.7.3)
py4j (0.9)
pycrypto (2.6.1)
pydot (1.0.28)
pygame (1.9.2a0)
Pygments (2.0.2)
pygraphviz (1.3rc2)
pyobjc-core (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-Accounts (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-AddressBook (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptKit (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptObjC (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-Automator (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-CFNetwork (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-Cocoa (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-Collaboration (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-CoreData (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-CoreLocation (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-CoreText (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-DictionaryServices (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-EventKit (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-ExceptionHandling (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-FSEvents (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-InputMethodKit (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-InstallerPlugins (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-InstantMessage (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-LatentSemanticMapping (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-LaunchServices (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-Message (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-OpenDirectory (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-PreferencePanes (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-PubSub (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-QTKit (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-Quartz (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-ScreenSaver (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-SearchKit (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-ServiceManagement (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-Social (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-SyncServices (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-SystemConfiguration (2.5.1)
pyobjc-framework-WebKit (2.5.1)
PyOpenGL (3.1.1a1)
pyOpenSSL (0.13.1)
pyparsing (2.0.1)
pyqtgraph (0.9.10)
PySDL2 (0.9.3)
python-dateutil (1.5)
python-igraph (0.6.5)
pytz (2013.7)
pyusb (1.0.0b2)
PyYAML (3.11)
pyzmq (16.0.2)
requests (2.4.0)
rosdep (0.11.2)
rosdistro (0.4.2)
rosinstall (0.7.5)
rosinstall-generator (0.1.11)
rospkg (1.0.35)
scandir (1.5)
scikit-learn (0.14.1)
scipy (0.13.0b1)
Scrapy (0.24.4)
setuptools (1.1.6)
simplegeneric (0.8.1)
simplejson (3.8.1)
singledispatch (3.4.0.3)
six (1.4.1)
snowballstemmer (1.2.0)
Sphinx (1.3.1)
sphinx-rtd-theme (0.1.8)
terminado (0.6)
textblob (0.8.3)
tinydb (3.1.2)
tornado (4.3)
tornado-systemd (1.0.1)
traitlets (4.3.1)
vboxapi (1.0)
vcstools (0.1.36)
wcwidth (0.1.7)
Werkzeug (0.10.4)
wget (2.2)
whatportis (0.6)
wheel (0.29.0)
wstool (0.1.6)
xattr (0.6.4)
zope.interface (4.1.1)
```

After I upgraded the jupyter I got a similar error:

```
bash-4.3$ sudo pip install -U jupyter --user
The directory '/Users/mona/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/mona/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting jupyter
  Downloading jupyter-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting nbconvert (from jupyter)
  Downloading nbconvert-5.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (372kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 378kB 932kB/s
Requirement already up-to-date: notebook in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from jupyter)
Requirement already up-to-date: ipykernel in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from jupyter)
Collecting jupyter-console (from jupyter)
  Downloading jupyter_console-5.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting ipywidgets (from jupyter)
  Downloading ipywidgets-6.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (46kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 1.3MB/s
Collecting qtconsole (from jupyter)
  Downloading qtconsole-4.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (104kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 112kB 1.4MB/s
Collecting jinja2 (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Downloading Jinja2-2.9.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (340kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 348kB 1.3MB/s
Collecting pygments (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Downloading Pygments-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (841kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 849kB 844kB/s
Requirement already up-to-date: mistune!=0.6 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter)
Collecting traitlets>=4.2 (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Downloading traitlets-4.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (74kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 81kB 3.0MB/s
Collecting nbformat (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Downloading nbformat-4.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (154kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 163kB 1.8MB/s
Requirement already up-to-date: entrypoints>=0.2.2 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from nbconvert->jupyter)
Collecting pandocfilters>=1.4.1 (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Downloading pandocfilters-1.4.1.tar.gz
Collecting testpath (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Downloading testpath-0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (82kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 3.1MB/s
Collecting jupyter-core (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Downloading jupyter_core-4.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (76kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 81kB 2.9MB/s
Collecting bleach (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Downloading bleach-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already up-to-date: ipython-genutils in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from notebook->jupyter)
Requirement already up-to-date: jupyter-client in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from notebook->jupyter)
Collecting tornado>=4 (from notebook->jupyter)
  Downloading tornado-4.4.2.tar.gz (460kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 460kB 1.6MB/s
Requirement already up-to-date: terminado>=0.3.3; sys_platform != "win32" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from notebook->jupyter)
Requirement already up-to-date: ipython>=4.0.0 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from ipykernel->jupyter)
Collecting prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.0 (from jupyter-console->jupyter)
  Downloading prompt_toolkit-1.0.13-py2-none-any.whl (247kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 256kB 1.1MB/s
Collecting widgetsnbextension~=2.0.0 (from ipywidgets->jupyter)
  Downloading widgetsnbextension-2.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.1MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.1MB 859kB/s
Requirement already up-to-date: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from jinja2->nbconvert->jupyter)
Requirement already up-to-date: enum34; python_version == "2.7" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from traitlets>=4.2->nbconvert->jupyter)
Collecting six (from traitlets>=4.2->nbconvert->jupyter)
  Downloading six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting decorator (from traitlets>=4.2->nbconvert->jupyter)
  Downloading decorator-4.0.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4 (from nbformat->nbconvert->jupyter)
  Downloading jsonschema-2.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already up-to-date: configparser>=3.5; python_version == "2.7" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from entrypoints>=0.2.2->nbconvert->jupyter)
Collecting html5lib!=0.9999,!=0.99999,<0.99999999,>=0.999 (from bleach->nbconvert->jupyter)
  Downloading html5lib-0.9999999.tar.gz (889kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 890kB 1.1MB/s
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.1 (from jupyter-client->notebook->jupyter)
  Downloading python_dateutil-2.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (194kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 194kB 3.2MB/s
Requirement already up-to-date: pyzmq>=13 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from jupyter-client->notebook->jupyter)
Requirement already up-to-date: singledispatch in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from tornado>=4->notebook->jupyter)
Collecting certifi (from tornado>=4->notebook->jupyter)
  Downloading certifi-2017.1.23-py2.py3-none-any.whl (382kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 389kB 1.8MB/s
Collecting backports_abc>=0.4 (from tornado>=4->notebook->jupyter)
  Downloading backports_abc-0.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already up-to-date: ptyprocess in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from terminado>=0.3.3; sys_platform != "win32"->notebook->jupyter)
Requirement already up-to-date: pexpect; sys_platform != "win32" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->jupyter)
Requirement already up-to-date: backports.shutil-get-terminal-size; python_version == "2.7" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->jupyter)
Requirement already up-to-date: simplegeneric>0.8 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->jupyter)
Collecting setuptools>=18.5 (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->jupyter)
  Downloading setuptools-34.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (389kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 399kB 2.0MB/s
Requirement already up-to-date: pathlib2; python_version == "2.7" or python_version == "3.3" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->jupyter)
Requirement already up-to-date: pickleshare in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->jupyter)
Requirement already up-to-date: appnope; sys_platform == "darwin" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->jupyter)
Requirement already up-to-date: wcwidth in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->jupyter-console->jupyter)
Requirement already up-to-date: functools32; python_version == "2.7" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4->nbformat->nbconvert->jupyter)
Requirement already up-to-date: appdirs>=1.4.0 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from setuptools>=18.5->ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->jupyter)
Requirement already up-to-date: packaging>=16.8 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from setuptools>=18.5->ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->jupyter)
Requirement already up-to-date: scandir; python_version < "3.5" in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pathlib2; python_version == "2.7" or python_version == "3.3"->ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->jupyter)
Collecting pyparsing (from packaging>=16.8->setuptools>=18.5->ipython>=4.0.0->ipykernel->jupyter)
  Downloading pyparsing-2.1.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (56kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 3.2MB/s
Installing collected packages: jinja2, pygments, six, decorator, traitlets, jupyter-core, jsonschema, nbformat, pandocfilters, testpath, html5lib, bleach, nbconvert, prompt-toolkit, jupyter-console, widgetsnbextension, ipywidgets, qtconsole, jupyter, certifi, backports-abc, tornado, python-dateutil, setuptools, pyparsing
  Running setup.py install for pandocfilters ... done
  Running setup.py install for html5lib ... done
  Running setup.py install for tornado ... done
Successfully installed backports-abc-0.5 bleach-1.5.0 certifi-2017.1.23 decorator-4.0.11 html5lib-0.9999999 ipywidgets-6.0.0 jinja2-2.9.5 jsonschema-2.6.0 jupyter-1.0.0 jupyter-console-5.1.0 jupyter-core-4.3.0 nbconvert-5.1.1 nbformat-4.3.0 pandocfilters-1.4.1 prompt-toolkit-1.0.13 pygments-2.2.0 pyparsing-2.1.10 python-dateutil-2.6.0 qtconsole-4.2.1 setuptools-34.3.0 six-1.10.0 testpath-0.3 tornado-4.4.2 traitlets-4.3.2 widgetsnbextension-2.0.0
bash-4.3$ jupyter notebook
Error executing Jupyter command 'notebook': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Have you tried [conda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) before? It is a Python distribution makes package management much easier.

Comment: Yes, I have used it and I have it in my other machine. I am planning not to use it here.

Comment: From [jupyter official page](http://jupyter.org/install.html), installation using `conda` is recommended. It might be a good idea to `conda`.

Answer (score 2):

The error means that an executable called `jupyter-notebook` is not on your PATH. Since you are doing `--user` installs on macOS, scripts are going in `$HOME/Library/Python/2.7/bin`, which needs to be on your PATH and isn't by default. If that's the case, you can add it with:

```
export PATH="$HOME/Library/Python/2.7/bin:$PATH"
```

which you can add to ~/.bashrc.

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for. Thank you for the explanation.